# LatinIME accessibility on key changed when is long pressed

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a custom keyboard that extends InputMethodService, but i don't know why accessibility doesn't work like GBoard keyboard when a key changed when is long pressed.

I've tried to set accessibility when a key is pressed and it works, but i'd don't know where do can i set when a new key get focus when long pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure i totally understood what you are looking for but maybe check this.
in MoreKeysKeyboardView.java

```
protected void onKeyInput(final Key key, final int x, final int y) {
    final int code = key.getCode();
    if (code == Constants.CODE_OUTPUT_TEXT) {
        mListener.onTextInput(mCurrentKey.getOutputText());
    } else if (code != Constants.CODE_UNSPECIFIED) {
        if (getKeyboard().hasProximityCharsCorrection(code)) {
            mListener.onCodeInput(code, x, y, false /* isKeyRepeat */);
        } else {
            mListener.onCodeInput(code, Constants.NOT_A_COORDINATE, Constants.NOT_A_COORDINATE,
                    false /* isKeyRepeat */);
        }
    }
}
```